# How to store data permanent in Smartphone

Tags: android, database, storage

How can I save data/variables in the storage of my Smartphone? I want to read and write to these variables in my application.
These can be simple strings like usernames, IDs or passwords. But these variables can also be own class object with multiple byte arrays and lists of byte arrays.
I've heard from sharedPreferences but i think with them i can only save the standard objects like strings and numbers.
Hope you have some tipps

Comment: Android supports SQLite databases. Although, they can not be said to be permanent, Db is cleared when the app's data is cleared or the app is uninstalled.

Comment: You can store in SQLite database in inside of Assert Folder and access them in your app.

Comment: @VishalPatolia **1** - The data would be read-only, unless you don't copy it and use the copy. **2** - The database would be erased upon uninstall, with all the assets folder.

Comment: @BobMalooga no not data not erase in app uninstall time only one thing data is read only.

Comment: @VishalPatolia The whole assets folder will be erased upon uninstall, including the database

Comment: @BobMalooga i create one Quotes app and database file quotes.db store in assert folder and access data when uninstall app assert folder db file not erase.

Comment: @VishalPatolia The assets folder is **part of the apk**.

Comment: @BobMalooga but whenever i uninstall app and after install my asset folder inside db file not erase.

Comment: No. It's erased with th rest of the apk. But then you **re-add** it again by installing the app once more. So you have the **feeling that it's not uninstalled**.

Answer (score 1):

There are different possibilities.

**1)** Classic way :

Android uses a SQlite database : it is the place where there are contacts, sms, mms and everything in your phone.

You can learn [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)  how to use the android default database.

**2)** ORM way :

An ORM is a tool used to communicate more simply with the database. You can store, delete or get all objects of your db with one line of code. There are different ORM for android, I use Sugar ORM, because it's very simple to implement and use. Try to read the documentation here : [sugar getting started](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html)

If you start in the world of Android, I recommand you to learn the classic way. But keep in mind that ORM is increasingly used !

Comment: With SQlite is it possible to store byte arrays and arrays of byte arrays. Maybe a example will help to understand: a username should saved as byte array, so i can read it and compare it. There is also a list of group IDs (all are byte arrays), so i want to read out the list and compare each id with a given ID.

Comment: I think that store a list as entity is not possible, you have to create a specific structure like a table for `groupId` which is composed of the ID and the foreign key to the owner user. But, an other way to do that is to use sugar orm and create a User class with a list of ID and a username, then you create an id class which contains the username as String and save it thanks to ORM. Have a look here : https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/60

Answer (score 0):

A good point to start with it is Androids [SQLite databases](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm). You can make data permanent by writing it manually into a file on your sd card for example. Read more about it in the link.